# Getting variance correct with Akka actors?

Tags: scala, akka, scala-generics, f-bounded-polymorphism

I am frequently encountering the following issue when using generics and Akka actors:

```
trait AuctionParticipantActor[P <: AuctionParticipant[P]]
  extends StackableActor {


  override def receive: Receive = {
    case message: Handled =>
      participant = participant.handle(message)
      super.receive(message)
    case message =>
      super.receive(message)
  }

  protected var participant: P

}
```

The `AuctionParticipantActor` is just a wrapper around an immutable `AuctionParticipant`.  I need that the type `P` is covariant and I am not sure what is the best way to achieve this.

Alternatively, for my use-cases I don't think I even need to parameterize the `AuctionParticipantActor`.  I could have something like:

```
trait AuctionParticipantActor
  extends StackableActor {


  override def receive: Receive = {
    case message: Handled =>
      participant = participant.handle(message)
      super.receive(message)
    case message =>
      super.receive(message)
  }

  protected var participant: AuctionParticipant[???]

}
```

But in this case, I am not sure what to put in place of ??? in order to respect the type bound. If anyone thinks that my problem is with the design, please say so.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use [f-bounded-polymorphism](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html) why do you need `AuctionParticipant` to be generic? What is the meaning of type parameter `P` in `AuctionParticipant[P]` then? If, as you said, `AuctionParticipantActor` is just a wrapper over `AuctionParticipant` and if `AuctionParticipantActor` is no longer generic then maybe `AuctionParticipant` shouldn't be either.

```
trait AuctionParticipantActor
  extends StackableActor {


  override def receive: Receive = {
    case message: Handled =>
      participant = participant.handle(message)
      super.receive(message)
    case message =>
      super.receive(message)
  }

  protected var participant: AuctionParticipant

}

trait AuctionParticipant {
  // ...
}
```

Otherwise if `AuctionParticipant` still should be generic (i.e. there is some other meaning of `P`) then maybe you can use [existential type](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/existential-types-in-scala):

```
trait AuctionParticipantActor
  extends StackableActor {


  override def receive: Receive = {
    case message: Handled =>
      participant = participant.handle(message)
      super.receive(message)
    case message =>
      super.receive(message)
  }

  protected var participant: AuctionParticipant[_]

}

trait AuctionParticipant[P] {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: To be clear, I need F-bounded polymorphism for `AuctionParticipant` trait (methods of this trait return a sub-class) as such I think the existential type parameter will not compile as it will violate type bounds.

Comment: @davidrpugh You didn't write definition of `AuctionParticipant`. I guess you should update your question.

Comment: @davidrpugh Existential type can be different. They can be `AuctionParticipant[_ <: UpperBound]` or `AuctionParticipant[_ >: LowerBound]` if necessary. What about `protected var participant: AuctionParticipant[_ <: AuctionParticipant[_]]`? Does it compile?

Comment: @davidrpugh So, what about `AuctionParticipant[_ <: AuctionParticipant[_]]`?